# how to add / read multiple data centers properties from spring boot / java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing an application where I will have 1 to N number of data centers details passed from properties file. for ex:..

```
myapp.ds1.domain.name=https://www.ds1.com
myapp.ds1.domain.username=us1
myapp.ds1.domain.password=pw1

myapp.ds2.domain.name=https://www.ds2.com
myapp.ds2.domain.username=us2
myapp.ds2.domain.password=pw2

.
.
.
.

myapp.dsn.domain.name=https://www.dsn.com
myapp.dsn.domain.username=usn
myapp.dsn.domain.password=pwn
```

I don't know how many fixed data centers information i will be getting, but what ever is there, I need to read it in my spring boot code.

I know if I want to read a particular value I can use

```
@Value("${myapp.ds.username:default}")
```

But this dynamic configuration, how to do it ? Any leads would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The @Value annotation is used to read the environment or application property value in Java code.

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
```

If the property is not found while running the application, Spring Boot throws the Illegal Argument exception as Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.name' in value "${spring.application.name}".

To resolve the placeholder issue, we can set the default value for the property using the syntax given below

```
@Value("${property_key_name:default_value}")
```

for example :-

```
@Value("${myproperty_key_name:mydefault_value}")
```

Please note You will use @Value to read the properties config file.

Comment: I know using the @Value annotation to read the static property file. and that I mentioned in the ticket as well. my question is to read the dynamic properties.

Comment: got it. Have you explored the option of @DynmicPropertySource ? You can find detailed explanation here.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamicpropertysource